# TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-timers'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to use the Vue plugin "Vue Timers" in my application on a component with `lang="ts` set up. Another component uses this plugin just fine, but that component is not using TypeScript.

When I compile, I get the following error:

```
  [tsl] ERROR in /src/renderer/components/ApplicationStatus.vue.ts(8,36)
        TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-timers'. '/node_modules/vue-timers/index.min.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

I've tried creating a `shim.d.ts` file with the line:

```js
declare module 'vue-timers';
```

But that didn't really help. Not sure how to proceed on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.d.ts` files should be in the included source paths (see the `include` property in [`tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)), or else `tsc` won't pick it up. For a Vue CLI project, the `src` directory (and all subdirectories) are in the included source paths; and you'll find other `.d.ts` files there. Put your `shims.d.ts` (containing the module declaration) in that directory to resolve the error.

Comment: In the electron project, there's a subdirectory in src "renderer" which is where the vue code lives. the .d.ts file should live in there?

Comment: Ah,  looks like just adding the line on the tsconfig.json did the trick! `"include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.vue", "*.d.ts"],`